# How can I know from where the method is called?

Tags: python

I'm trying clean implement of Objective-C's category in Python, and found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13568709/2100702) to similar question of mine. I copied the code below:

**categories.py**

```
class category(object):
    def __init__(self, mainModule, override = True):
        self.mainModule = mainModule
        self.override = override

    def __call__(self, function):
        if self.override or function.__name__ not in dir(self.mainModule):
            setattr(self.mainModule, function.__name__, function)
```

But I do not want to waste namespace.
By using this `categories', there remains a variable as NoneType object like below:

```
>>> from categories import category
>>> class Test(object):
...     pass
... 
>>> @category(Test)
... def foobar(self, msg):
...     print msg
... 
>>> test = Test()
>>> test.foobar('hello world')
hello world
>>> type(foobar)
<type 'NoneType'>
>>>
```

I want it to be like below

```
>>> from categories import category
>>> class Test(object):
...     pass
... 
>>> @category(Test)
... def foobar(self, msg):
...     print msg
... 
>>> test = Test()
>>> test.foobar('hello world')
hello world
>>> type(foobar)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'foobar' is not defined
>>>
```

Is there anyway to delete it automatically like below?

```
    def __call__(self, function):
        if self.override or function.__name__ not in dir(self.mainModule):
            setattr(self.mainModule, function.__name__, function)
            del(somewhere.function.__name__)
```

I found that `sys._getframe` give me some useful information. But I couldn't make it by myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no way to automatically do that.  You would have to manually delete the name afterwards.  `category` here is a decorator, which means that

```
@category(Test)
def f():
    ...
```

is the same as

```
def f():
   ...
f = category(Test)(f)
```

Even if, from inside `category`, you could delete the name in the outer scope, it wouldn't be enough, because that name is rebound *after* the decorator executes.

The code that you linked to borders on an abuse of the decorator syntax.  Decorators are meant to provide a way to modify or extend the function they decorate, but that code relies on side-effects of the decorator (namely, assigning the function as a method of a class), and then discards the function.  But it can only "discard" it by returning None, so None remains bound to the function's name, as you saw.

I would recommend you follow the advice of the highest-voted answer on that question, and simply assign new methods to your classes.  There is no real need for an "infrastructure" like categories in Python, because you can just directly add new methods to existing classes whenever you want.

Comment: Thank you for giving me a answer. I'll change my plan and implement them more pythonic way!

Answer (score 0):

While I completely agree with what BrenBarn said, you could split the function removal into a later step. The problem is that after the decorator executed, the variable is reassigned. So you cannot perform the removal within the decorator itself.

You could however remember the functions and remove them from the module at a later point.

```
class category(object):
    functions = []

    def __init__(self, mainModule, override = True):
        self.mainModule = mainModule
        self.override = override

    def __call__(self, function):
        if self.override or function.__name__ not in dir(self.mainModule):
            setattr(self.mainModule, function.__name__, function)
            self.functions.append((inspect.getmodule(function), function.__name__))
            return self.dummy

    @staticmethod
    def dummy():
        pass

    @classmethod
    def cleanUp(cls):
        for module, name in cls.functions:
            if hasattr(module, name) and getattr(module, name) == cls.dummy:
                delattr(module, name)
        cls.functions = []
```

This `category` type will remember the functions it decorates and stores the names and modules they belong to for a later cleanup. The decorator also returns a special dummy function so that the cleanup can ensure that the variable was not reassigned later.

```
>>> class Test(object): pass
>>> @category(Test)
def foobar(self, msg):
    print(msg)

>>> @category(Test)
def hello_world(self):
    print('Hello world')

>>> test = Test()
>>> test.foobar('xy')
xy
>>> test.hello_world()
Hello world

>>> type(foobar)
<class 'function'>
>>> type(hello_world)
<class 'function'>

>>> category.cleanUp()

>>> type(foobar)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#26>", line 1, in <module>
    type(foobar)
NameError: name 'foobar' is not defined
>>> type(hello_world)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#27>", line 1, in <module>
    type(hello_world)
NameError: name 'hello_world' is not defined
```